# ISP Email Issue on Port 25

Tags: email

My ISP, a small, local “mom & pop” outfit, provides my email services.  For the last six months or so, my main email account frequently fails to update with the following message, “Could not connect to server mail.win.net; the connection was refused.”  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn’t.  Interestingly, my other two email accounts on this server almost always update without error.  These two “working” email accounts have very low volume.

The ISP tech guy insist that the problem is likely due to malware on my side.  Scans by MSCERT, Malwarebytes and Norton virus software reveal no malware on the PC.  The PC is not networked with other PC’s.  It is a standalone workstation connected to a Netgear switch that resides on a home, uVerse router.

How can I determine if I have a spam bot or some other malware on my workstation spewing out email on port 25 causing the ISP to reject a connection?  Are there tools available that would allow me to monitor this and identify then delete the offending software?  If this is indeed the problem, why doesn't the standard scanners pick this up?  **Or** does the ISP have some parameters set improperly limiting my main email account's connection to their mail server when volumes are high?

Comment: Your ISP might have a rate limiting or a limited number of mails one can send per day setup. Given that you characterize the working accounts as low-volume it sounds like the account in question is not low-volume, which might mean that it runs into some rate limits because is considered a spammer. Thus, first check with your ISP if the number of mails you want to send should be possible in the first place before assuming that the problem is caused by malware.

Comment: Steffen Ullrich, I usually send 3 or 4 emails in the morning first thing.  There's usually a dozen or so emails to be downloaded (1/2 of which are incoming spam).  That's it.  Nothing more.  I wouldn't think this would violate rate limits.  I'll check anyway.   I've also noticed that the problem is less noticeable when I keep my older emails archived and not setting in mail box.  I'm guessing that Thunderbird, my email package, is quicker at determining what needs to be downloaded when there are fewer items to be reviewed.  This might indicate that the ISP is also limiting connect time, too.

Comment: Since you say that the problem is port 25 - this is only for sending mail and not for retrieving. And actually usually today port 465 or 587 are used for submitting a mail to your ISP's mail server. Given that you specifically mention port 25 - what indicators do you have that this port is actually the problem? And in what situations exactly you get the error messages (sending mail, retrieving mail).

Comment: Also, if *"The ISP tech guy __insist__ that the problem is __likely__ due to malware on my side."* then ask him to provide more details about this claim (i.e. something different then just blaming you with *"I can see no problem on our side so it must be on your side"*) so that you can better track down what causes the problem on your site. And, is this `mail.win.net` a mail service provided by your ISP?

Comment: Steffen Ullrich, I *assumed*, with all the risks implied with assuming, that if it was a spam bot causing the problem it would manifest itself on Port 25.  Is there anything on Port 110 that I should be looking at?     Thanks for your input....Good Points!

Comment: Assuming that win.net is your ISP I must question the competence of this ISP: the webmail.win.net webmail interface (horde) is from 2006, the webmail2 (squirrelmail) from 2007, no support for encryption (TLS) for sending and receiving mails. In other words: I would doubt anything their support says. They run a lot of insecure software so I doubt that they have any knowledge of IT security or of running a stable network. Claiming that the customer is the problem is the easiest thing they can do but it does not need to be true.

Comment: Time to switch mail providers....

Comment: Steffen Ullrich, On closer inspection the ports are actually,Incoming Mail Port: 110
Outgoing Mail Port: 587

Comment: Conor Mancone,  I have been wondering exactly the same thing.  Well, so much for "mom and pop"....  Thank you for your input ... despite its sobering implications.

Comment: @ArcZap: like I said, I very much doubt the competence of the ISP. *"Could not connect to server mail.win.net; the connection was refused.”* might actually be because your ISP's server cannot catch up with the load. That it is more with one account than with the others might be either because you check your mail more often (and maybe especially at busy times) or because the other accounts have a slightly different configuration.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a "packet capture". You want to capture all traffic on port 25 from your network and see:

1. volume of traffic
2. type of traffic
3. destination

If all looks ok, then it's not malware.

A small ISP blaming the customer and invoking malware/virus/sunspots/aliens as the culprit is nothing new.

Aside from the above, though, this really isn't a security concern but a networking troubleshooting concern.

Comment: schroeder,  Can you recommend a packet capture software package?  (Try saying those last four words quickly ;-)  )  Preferably open source?

Comment: there is really only one to consider: wireshark